# Poisson distribution problem with expected number

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

The number of typing errors made by a typist has a Poisson distribution with an average of three errors per five pages. If a page contains an error, the typist must retype the whole page. What is the expected number of pages that must be typed for a document that is 100 pages long?

I am not very familiar with distributions but I will give it a try:

Rate $λ = \frac {3}{5} = 0.6$

We are looking for the probability $P (X>0) = 1-P(X=0) = 0.45119$

Then we calculate the mean, $\frac {3}{5}.100 = 60$?

I don't know how to continue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would take $X_j$ as the number of times you type the $j^\text{th}-$page until the page is error free. You need to compute $\mathbb{E}\left(X_1 + \dots + X_{100} \right)$. Do know what the distribution of $X_j$ is?

Comment: @MatthewH. sorry, no, I don't know.

Comment: The probability of having to retype a page is $p=1-\exp(-0.6)$; the expected number of pages to retype is thus:  $100(p+p^2+p^3+p^4+...=100p/(1-p)$

Comment: @Honza I would expect the result to be >100, right? However, the result is 82.2

Comment: The distribution of $X_j$ is $\text{Geometric}\left(e^{-0.6}\right)$ which has expected value $e^{0.6}$. So your answer is $100e^{0.6}\approx 182$

Comment: My answer leads to 182,2, so the question must have asked for the EXTRA pages to be typed